# What are the meanings of the phrases DAY, RWYCC, 6/6/6 in ATIS?

Tags: phraseology, metar, atis, taf

What are the meanings of the phrases DAY, RWYCC, 6/6/6 in ATIS? I marked the section after QNH in yellow.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

RWYCC 6/6/6 means "Runway Condition Codes" of 6 (dry) for the first, middle, and last third of the runway.

RCC's, as they're also known, are a relatively new way to report the state of the runway surface, and range from 6 = dry to 0 = nil braking. The FAA published [this document](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/about/initiatives/talpa/TALPA-Airport-RCAM.pdf) with further explanations. They're reported in that format of three separated values; the most common are 6/6/6 (i.e. runway is dry) and 5/5/5 (i.e. runway is wet but good braking). Lower values are generally seen only with snow/ice or heavy rain + standing water. The convention allows for reports differentiating the condition of different areas of the runway, such as 5/5/1 (last third has "poor" braking action), but that seems to be rarely used.

One might assume that "DAY" is simply reporting that it is daylight there, but without context (where is this report from?) that's all I can offer; that isn't a report used in ATIS broadcasts that I've seen.